# Convert Red-Black tree to AVL tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree, red-black-tree

I am trying to convert Red-Black Tree to AVL Tree but am unable to do that. Please provide with a pseudo algorithm or an implementation in some language

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't directly, because some RB trees are not valid AVL trees (because they're too unbalanced). You could, of course, simply create a new AVL tree and insert all the items in the RB tree into it. Alternatively, you'd have to strip the colors and do rebalancing operations to get all the leaves' depths close enough.